# ignore specific file when using glob to get folder files

Tags: javascript, node.js

im using glob to get all folder content inside my node js application,
I want that its ignore one file,there is a way to to it in elegant way?

```
 glob("folder/*.js", function (err, extensions) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd argument is `options`, which you can set to ignore a path. [Reference](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options)

```
glob("folder/*.js", {ignore: ['folder/dont_want.js']}, function (err, extensions) {
```